# Как реализовать подобие транзакции в микросервисах

Tags: golang, микросервисы

Есть 2 сервиса общаются по grpc, нужно гарантировать консистентность данных в обоих.
Например нужно создать пользователя в сервисе 1, как-то с ним поработать и записать в базу только если запрос в сервисе 2 был удачным, если же нет откатить.

Какие решения у себя применяете?

Comment: Ровно так и пишем, в случае успешности - сохраняем, в случае ошибки - не сохраняем :) суть вопроса не понятна вообще, вы хотите компонент который будет делать что? сам отслеживать успешность вашего grpc ? по какому критерию считать запрос успешным? =)

Answer (score 3):

Есть два варианта, как реализовать транзакции в микросервисах:

1. Двухфазная фиксация.

На подготовительном этапе все микросервисы, участвующие в работе, готовятся к фиксации и уведомляют координатора, что готовы завершить транзакцию. Затем на следующем этапе либо происходит фиксация, либо координатор транзакции выдает всем микросервисам команду выполнить откат.

2. Согласованность в конечном счете и компенсация / SAGA

При таком подходе распределенная транзакция выполняется как совокупность асинхронных локальных транзакций на соответствующих микросервисах. Микросервисы обмениваются информацией через шину событий.

Более подробно можно прочитать здесь: https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/522366/